# set the UITabBarItem in UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

```
UITabBar *frameTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 698, 1024, 70)];
UITabBarItem *frameTabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fee" image:nil tag:0];
UITabBarItem *frameTabBarItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Dev" image:nil tag:1];
NSArray *frameTabBarItemArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:frameTabBarItem1,frameTabBarItem2,nil];
[frameTabBar setItems:frameTabBarItemArray];
```

But there isnt any Item displayed in my UITabBar.
What's wrong with my code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that the items are there, you just can't see them because you didn't set an image and the labels are out of your visible frame.

```
UITabBar *frameTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 698, 1024, 70)];
```

698 + 70 = 768

768 is the height of an iPad in landscape orientation. But, if there is a statusbar, the usable frame is 20 pixel smaller. And the 20 pixel are exactly the height that would hide your tab labels.

So just subtract 20 pixel from the y position and you are good.

```
UITabBar *frameTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 678, 1024, 70)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that You should implement the tabBarDelegate in your header file and set your ViewController as the delegate?

in your .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate>
```

in your .m file:

```
frameTabBar.delegate=self;
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but i think it isn't delegate issue.

Answer (score 0):

try it m sure it will work......

```
[self.view addSubview:frameTabBar];
```

Thanks
Pankaj Chauhan